# Outlook: Switched from POP to IMAP. Mail doesn't send from OUTBOX when From address doesn't match default IMAP folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, imap, pop3, sendmail

I wanted to start using IMAP for all my emails, that i am currently accessing using POP. There are about 10 different email address that i previously had all going to 1 PST file.

Creating new IMAP email accounts for all the previous POP email accounts, caused Outlook to create new data files for each of them.  I set one of the IMAP accounts to act as the default email account.

So now when i send an email, if i set the send 'FROM' this account to something other than the default email account, it doesn't send the email, it just sits in the OUTBOX of the default data PST file.

What i want to do is be able to set the 'from' address to something other than the default, since i'm dealing with 10 different emails.  I was able to choose my 'from' when my email files were POP and the email was always sent with the 'correct' FROM.

so what am i not understanding why only 1 account can be used as the SEND account.

tx!

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple profiles. <kbd>**Outlook 2007**</kbd>

[Switch to another e-mail profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-to-another-Outlook-e-mail-profile-be3b617f-3f64-43d3-9037-8313b431803c?CorrelationId=d79070ab-4e6d-419f-9705-cf0da9b97632&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

[How to create profile in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829918)

[Add or remove an e-mail account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829918)

[Open, change, or close Outlook data files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-change-or-close-Outlook-data-files-448921ca-db72-47e6-ab9c-63a2d4b22f79?CorrelationId=5441f556-09f4-45a0-bed0-ea79db78b58e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: multiple e-mail profiles is a terrible solution to this.   I am 1 user, who wants to see my multiple email accounts in one place, just like i had before.  I just want to be able to send email from the different emails like i did before.   what are my options with that.   Is it that you can't use a different IMAP sender than the designated default?  sounds odd to me, but maybe there are better alternatives. or what are the restrictions on IMAP use?